# #temp table not being dropped

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have this code that should drop a temp table if it exists, but I'm still getting an error: `Cannot drop the table '#jobsconsumed', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.` Could someone help me out? My I.T. admin doesn't think it's a permissions issue.

```
IF (SELECT object_id('TempDB.#jobsconsumed')) IS NULL
    BEGIN
    DROP Table #jobsconsumed
END
```

Comment: I think you should try two dots: `TempDB..#jobsconsumed`

Comment: What does the 2 dots do?

Comment: And probably `IS NOT NULL` is the logic you really want.  Why delete something that doesn't exist?

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff , that was it. Still curious about those dots though...

Comment: It tells sql server to look for the table in all schema's, if I'm not mistaken. `TempDB.#jobsconsumed` would look for the schema `#jobsconsumed`. But I have to admit I haven't used it often, and I'm not at all sure...

Comment: Ah ok. I originally found this code on another question here on SO, but it might have only applied to SQL-Server 2000. Oh well.

Comment: Oh I see where I was getting confused - I thought the `END` was the `END IF` of the `IF` statement. `BEGIN` and `END` seem to have their own meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
IF (SELECT object_id('TempDB.#jobsconsumed')) IS NULL
    BEGIN
    DROP Table #jobsconsumed
END
```

The above code will  enter Begin clause , only when TempTable is present..

To check and drop TempTable,correct way is below

```
IF object_id('Tempdb..#test') is Not null  
 is same as
  IF object_id('Tempdb.dbo.#test') is Not null  
Drop Table #test
```

There is no need of Begin And END clause in this case,since IF Will execute immediate statement when true

some tests on schema aspects of TEMP tables..

```
  use tempdb; 

 create schema hr

 create table hr.#t( c int) --this will work
 create table #t( c int) --this will fail

 create table #t1 --no schema ,so it will create a temp table in DBO Schema by default.

 --To drop the table
 drop table #t --this will drop across all schemas
```

Comment: Question: I'm using this line to put values into the #temp table. `(SELECT t.ref_num, t.ref_line_suf INTO #jobsconsumed FROM ISW_LPTrans AS t WHERE t.item = @item AND t.lot = @lot AND (t.trans_type = 'I' OR t.trans_type = 'W'))` But according to your answer this should fail because I'm using `#jobsconsumed` instead of `dbo.#jobsconsumed`. Why isn't it failing?

Comment: it won't fail ,bcoz it will by default create in dbo .schema

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me for **MS SQL 2017**

```
use tempdb
go

IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#yourtemptable', N'U') IS NOT NULL   
DROP TABLE #yourtemptable;  
GO
```